# Vertical-alignment with display block and span

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange a text with a background over the full line (used span with display block), which should be vertically-aligned at the bottom next to an img.

Unfortunately vertical alignment only works on inline elements and not on block.
Using line-height for vertical alignment on the parent also didn't work since the background then spans over the whole block.

Any ideas/workarounds?

```css
.block {
  background: #324234;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.image {
  background: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <img class="image" src="background-x" width="100" height="100" align="left" />
  <span class="block">We do stuff</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flex for this.

```css
.block {
  background: #324234; 
  display:block; 
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:0;
}

.image {
  background: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
h2{
  border:1px solid green;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <img class="image" src="background-x" width="100" height="100" />
  <span class="block">We do stuff</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Looked into flex myself it, but could'nt make it work. I didn't need the border but thanks, anyway;)